# java script function for filling a list

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function that enters personal information into empty list and save them. I want to add one by one but if first name and last name have entered before, show me "user has been added before" and does not add repeated user.my function does not work and i do not understand why? list is still empty!!

```
var personalInfo = [];

function addEmployee(firstName, lastName, hourPerMonth, salaryPerHour) {
  if (hourPerMonth > 160) return 'hourPerMonth is too much';
  
    personalInfo.push({
      'firstName': firstName,
      'lastName': lastName,
      'hourPerMonth': hourPerMonth,
      'salaryPerHour': salaryPerHour
    });

  for (let index = 0; index < personalInfo.length; index++) {
    let item = personalInfo[index];
    if (item.firstName !== firstName && item.lastName !== lastName) {
      personalInfo.push({
        'firstName': firstName,
        'lastName': lastName,
        'hourPerMonth': hourPerMonth,
        'salaryPerHour': salaryPerHour
      });
    }
  }
  return personalInfo;
}


//for example:
addEmployee('alex', 'ortemi', 134, 23); //ok
addEmployee('olivia', 'zikari', 144, 26); //ok
addEmployee('alex', 'ortemi', 132, 13); // error : user has been added before
```

any solution would be my appreciate

I have tried couple of solutions but i did not get answer

Comment: Why does your function use a global var `personalInfo` but then return `personalInfo`? Besides that, since the array starts out empty, your loop never does any work, so this is why nothing happens.

Comment: This is a piece of my code and I want to write some functions but this is a first one. can you give me a hand ? how can i change my code @mardubbles

Comment: I already stated that your for loop never iterates because `personalInfo` is empty and thus there is nothing to iterate over. As a "helping hand", you need an `if` statement before the loop to add the employee if the list is empty. Then, if its not, that's when you use your code where you check the array for uniqueness.

Comment: Seems kinda strange that you know about for loops and object literals, but not an `if` statement?

Comment: it does not work. I change it but just accept one input and second input overwrites it

Comment: " I change it but" but you didn't change it *here*. Where does it not work? Your question is so easy, but I'm to believe you even wrote the "for statement" and have "implicit objects defined"? Where is your code? You can write (copy/paste) code, whuptiydoo. Congratulations. Where is *your* code?

Comment: I was confused . @mardubbles

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```js
let personalInfo = [];

//adds user to DB
const addEmployee = (
    firstName,
    lastName,
    workHoursPerMonth,
    salaryPerHour,
    dataBase = personalInfo
) => {
    let isDuplicate = false;
    /*loop over the DB to check if firstName and lastName comb. has a duplicate*/
    for (let i = 0; i < dataBase.length; i++) {
        // check if the input firstName and lastName combination match dataBase[i] element
        if (
            workHoursPerMonth < 160 &&
            (dataBase.length === 0 ||
                !(
                    dataBase[i].firstName === firstName &&
                    dataBase[i].lastName === lastName
                ))
        ) {
        } else {
            isDuplicate = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!isDuplicate) {
        dataBase.push({});
        dataBase[dataBase.length - 1].firstName = firstName;
        dataBase[dataBase.length - 1].lastName = lastName;
        dataBase[dataBase.length - 1].workHoursPerMonth = workHoursPerMonth;
        dataBase[dataBase.length - 1].salaryPerHour = salaryPerHour;
        isDuplicate = true;
        return `user '${firstName} ${lastName}' was successfully added.`;
    } else {
        return `We couldn't Add user: '${firstName} ${lastName}' ! perhaps cause of duplicated data or irregular work hour`;
    }
};

addEmployee("alex", "ortemi", 134, 23); //ok
addEmployee("olivia", "zikari", 144, 26); //ok
addEmployee("alex", "ortemi", 132, 13); // the function filters that succesfully
console.log(personalInfo);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).